# How to avoid spawned object overlapping with other object in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have this script that will transform the position of an object called "target" you shoot them with raycast, and i have 5 of them each with different position.
When i shoot one of the target, it sometimes overlap with other target because it spawned with random range.

```
    public void Shoot()
    {
        Ray gunRay = new Ray(camera.position, camera.forward);
        if(Physics.Raycast(gunRay,out RaycastHit hit, bulletRange))
        {
            if(hit.collider.gameObject.TryGetComponent(out Target target ))
            {
                target.transform.position = new Vector3(Random.Range(-6.2f, 6.25f), Random.Range(3.2f, -3.95f), 0f);
            }
        }
    }
```

How do i avoid a target overlapping with other target?

Answer (score 0):

You can store the value of your new possible destination inside a variable of type Vector3, to check if area is occupied use something like [Physics.CheckBox](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.CheckBox.html) or another shape like sphere or capsule if it better fits.

You can input the size of your target collider or the renderer bounding box to keep it more modular.

[Physics.Overlap](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.OverlapBox.html) and alike could work as option too if more info is needed from the hit colliders in the check.

To make sure of a result use a loop to keep trying until we find one, add a max limit to handle if no possibles are found so we don't stay stuck.

If you want only check for target colliders, you can create a LayerMask field adding it to Physics function.

something like this could work as example:

```
    [SerializeField] private LayerMask targetLayer;

private Vector3 GetRandomPosition()
{
    int tries = 0;
    int maxTries = 6000;

    do
    {
        var newPos = new Vector3(Random.Range(-6.2f, 6.25f), Random.Range(3.2f, -3.95f), 0f);
        // if we did not hit any colliders of targetLayer we return this valid position
        if (!Physics.CheckBox(newPos, Vector3.one * 2, Quaternion.identity, targetLayer))
        {
            return newPos;
        }

        tries++;

    } while (tries < maxTries);

    //handle if did not find a valid pos perhaps a distant pos to later try again from a pool
    return Vector3.one * 500;
}
```

then change the method to

```
        if (Physics.Raycast(gunRay, out RaycastHit hit, bulletRange))
    {
        if (hit.collider.gameObject.TryGetComponent(out Target target))
        {
            target.transform.position = GetRandomPosition();
        }
    }
```

Of course handling when a position isn't found you can perhaps put the object back in a pool and try again;